# How can I make the function dynamically update the html?

Tags: javascript, html, function

Upon loading of html page function `checkTweetLength` is called. This function is meant to update the number of characters typed in the textarea. But this function doesn't update the html page as it runs only once during the page load. How can I make this function dynamically update the html page ?

```
// JavaScript Document

window.onload = function(){
    checkTweetLength();
};

function checkTweetLength() {
    var tweet = document.getElementById("tweet_entered");
    if(tweet.value.length > 140) {
        //alert('Hey');
        document.getElementById("tweet_length").innerHTML = tweet.value.length - 140; 
    }else {
        //alert('else block');
        document.getElementById("tweet_length").innerHTML = tweet.value.length;
    }
}
```

Comment: You want it updating on each keypress in the input field or when the field loses focus or, other?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
document.getElementById("tweet_entered").onKeyUp = checkTweetLength;
```

Answer (score 1):

Just bind it to the textarea using `<onchange>`.  e.g. `<textarea onchange=checkTweetLength(); >`

(edit) or use `onkeyup` to record changes as the user types...

Answer (score 0):

You can set an interval after which the function will be called. Like in below case your function will be called after 3 seconds.

```
setTimeout(function(){checkTweetLength()}, 3000);
```

Or you can call it if there is any activity (mousemove or keypress)

```
$(document).bind( "mousemove keypress", function () {
 checkTweetLength();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to bind a keypress or change event to the text area.

Here is a working [jsbin](http://jsbin.com/muvep/1/edit)

```
    window.onload = function(){
    var tweet = document.getElementById("tweet_entered");
    tweet.onkeypress = checkTweetLength;
}
    function checkTweetLength() {
    if(this.value.length > 140) {
        console.log('Hey');
        document.getElementById("tweet_length").innerHTML =   140 - this.value.length; 
    }else {
        console.log('else block');
        document.getElementById("tweet_length").innerHTML = this.value.length;
    }
 }
```

Now as soon as the user start typing in the textarea, the count will update

Hope it's useful to you